# Inset in GeoGraphics

Tags: geographics

how to place `Inset` (or custom `GeoLabels`) in `GeoGraphics`?
I've tried this

```
pos = FindGeoLocation["Adelaide, Australia"]
geo = GeoGraphics[
   GeoDisk[pos, 5000]
   ];
Show[
 geo,
 Epilog -> {Inset["Place", pos, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20}]}
 ]
```

but it is showing nothing but the map and the disk.

Thanks,
F

Answer (score 3):

```
GeoGraphics[{GeoDisk[pos, 5000],Inset[Text[Style["Place", 20]], pos]}]
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
GeoGraphics[{GeoDisk[pos, 5000], Text[Style["Place", 20], pos]}]
```

> same picture

And slight modification of OP's code:

```
Show[
  geo,
  Epilog -> {Inset["Place", 
    GeoGridPosition[GeoPosition[pos], "Mercator"][[1]], 
    BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20}]}
  ]
```

> same picture

Comment: thanks, it was very useful!